# Different formatting of nearly exact structures by clang-format

Tags: c++, clang-format

I would like to use clang-format to autoformat my source code, but I can't understand it's behaviour with similar structures. Please see following C++ code:

```
static someStructLongName structInstanceLong{
    Method1LongLong,       
    structInstanceMethod1, 
    structInstanceMethod1,
    structInstanceMethod3,
    structInstanceMethod4,
    structInstanceMethod5,
    structInstanceMethod6,
    structInstanceMethod7,
    structInstanceMethod8
};

static someStructLongName structInstanceLong{
    Method1,
    structInstanceMethod1,
    structInstanceMethod1,
    structInstanceMethod3,
    structInstanceMethod4,
    structInstanceMethod5,
    structInstanceMethod6,
    structInstanceMethod7,
    structInstanceMethod8
};
```

And when I format it with clang-format, using my custom config file (attached at the bottom of the post), I get following output:

```
static someStructLongName structInstanceLong{Method1LongLing,       structInstanceMethod1, structInstanceMethod1,
                                             structInstanceMethod3, structInstanceMethod4, structInstanceMethod5,
                                             structInstanceMethod6, structInstanceMethod7, structInstanceMethod8};

static someStructLongName structInstanceLong{Method1,
                                             structInstanceMethod1,
                                             structInstanceMethod1,
                                             structInstanceMethod3,
                                             structInstanceMethod4,
                                             structInstanceMethod5,
                                             structInstanceMethod6,
                                             structInstanceMethod7,
                                             structInstanceMethod8};
```

Second option is preferred, but I can't understand which rule is responsible for this behaviour, so what is about to change to force this result for all structures.

Interesting thing - when I use this online tool:
https://zed0.co.uk/clang-format-configurator/
loading my configuration and above code everything looks like expected.

Below clang-format custom config:

```
---
AccessModifierOffset: '-4'
AlignEscapedNewlinesLeft: 'true'
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: 'true'
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: None
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: 'false'
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: 'false'
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: 'false'
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: 'true'
BinPackParameters: 'false'
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: 'NonAssignment'
BraceWrapping:
  AfterClass:      false
  AfterControlStatement: false
  AfterEnum:       false
  AfterFunction:   false
  AfterNamespace:  false
  AfterStruct:     false
  AfterUnion:      false
  BeforeCatch:     true
  BeforeElse:      true
  IndentBraces:    false
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: 'false'
BreakConstructorInitializersBeforeComma: 'true'
ColumnLimit: '120'
ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: 'false'
ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth: '4'
ContinuationIndentWidth: '4'
Cpp11BracedListStyle: 'true'
DerivePointerAlignment: 'false'
DisableFormat: 'false'
ExperimentalAutoDetectBinPacking: 'false'
IndentCaseLabels: 'false'
IndentWidth: '4'
IndentWrappedFunctionNames: 'false'
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: 'false'
Language: Cpp
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: '1'
NamespaceIndentation: All
PointerAlignment: Left
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: 'true'
SpaceBeforeParens: ControlStatements
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: 'false'
SpacesInAngles: 'false'
SpacesInCStyleCastParentheses: 'false'
SpacesInParentheses: 'false'
Standard: Cpp11
TabWidth: '4'
UseTab: Never

...
```

Answer (score 0):

### I used a tool called clang-format configurator, this will format your code like your second option

BasedOnStyle: Chromium

AlignEscapedNewlinesLeft: 'true'

AlignTrailingComments: 'true'

AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: 'false'

AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: 'true'

AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: All

BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: 'true'

ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: 'true'

IndentWidth: '1'

IndentWrappedFunctionNames: 'true'

KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: 'false'

SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: 'false'

...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's a lot of parameters and some of them conflicts with my already established rules. Are all these parameters really necessary to achieve this one thing?

Comment: Actually removing my configuration and using exactly this provided above I have not achieved expected results. I use clang-format 3.8 and 6.0

Comment: ---
BasedOnStyle: Chromium
AlignAfterOpenBracket: Align
AlignConsecutiveAssignments: 'false'
BinPackArguments: 'false'

...

Comment: Finally - this one parameter "BinPackArguments: 'false'" works for me. Many thanks